# Get Most used Search Queries in SharePoint online 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am working on creating a dashboard with web analytics. Here,  I need to get most used search keywords in SharePoint  online.

I know that I can get top search keywords in Popularity Trends and Search reports. But what I need is getting  most used search key words in to a list which I can show them using a data view web part Or any other option.(like web part or java script)

Appreciate if any one can help me.

Thank you